# How to set the max size of a log file in YII?

Tags: yii

I can see that Yii has "setMaxLogFiles" function [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileLogRoute#setMaxLogFiles-detail), but I don't know how to use it. I figured you'd be able to just add it in config/main.php, but it doesn't seem there is a place to put it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that it's in your configuration file:

```
'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'trace, info',
                    'categories'=>'system.*',
                ),
                array(
                    'class'=>'CEmailLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning',
                    'emails'=>'admin@example.com',
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

You can specify some options like the file size or the maximum number of log files:

```
array(
    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
    'levels'=>'trace, info',
    'categories'=>'system.*',
    'maxFileSize' => 99999,
    'maxLogFiles' => 1,
),
```

Source: [The Yii Guide about logging](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging#message-routing)